# ggplot2: is there a way to align the mean to the box plot and to align the legend text?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am a beginner with R and I this is my first attempt at using ggplot.

I keep running into problems: 1.) my means are not aligned with the dataset if the width of the box plot is kept constant. 2) I would like to have my legend text aligned to the left. I cant seem to find the right function for them.

```
Cellsize <- c(5.099, 6, 8, 9.01, 5, 4.323, 8.736, 6.84, 8.374, 9.21, 7.85, 4.323, 8.736, 7.84, 9.374)

Experiment <- c('Control', 'Control', 'Control', 'Genotype 1', 'Genotype 1', 'Genotype 1', 'Genotype 2', 'Genotype 2', 'Genotype 2', 'Genotype 1', 'Genotype 1', 'Genotype 1', 'Genotype 2', 'Genotype 2', 'Genotype 2')

DevAge <- c('30h', '30h', '30h', '30h', '30h', '30h', '30h', '30h', '30h', '48h', '48h', '48h', '48h', '48h', '48h')

df <- data.frame(Experiment, DevAge, Cellsize )
head(df, 15)

dfp<-ggplot(df, aes(x=DevAge, y=Cellsize, color=Experiment)) +
  geom_boxplot (outlier.fill = "red",outlier.color = "black",outlier.shape = 21, position = position_dodge2(preserve =c ("single"), padding= 0.2)) + 
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="point", shape=5, size=2, position=position_dodge(0.75)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 13, 2), limits = c (0, 13)) +
  theme_classic() + 
  labs(color= element_blank(), x="Developmental Age", y="Average cell size (\u03BCm)") + 
  scale_color_manual(values=c("black", "blue", "orange"),
                     labels =c ("Control", expression(italic("Genotype 1")), expression (italic ("Genotype 2")))
  ) 

dfp + theme(
  axis.title.x = element_text(size=16, family ="Arial", face="bold"), 
  axis.title.y = element_text(size=16, family ="Arial", face="bold"),
  axis.text.x = element_text(size=12, family ="Arial", face="bold", angle = 45, vjust = 0.5),
  axis.text.y = element_text(size=12, family ="Arial", face="bold"),
  legend.text = element_text(size=10, family ="Arial")
)

dfp
```

[image]

Comment: For a minimal reproducable example, please add libraries needed and leave away things such as font  as I get errors that windows can't find the font family in the windows data base. 
For the align use:  `+  theme(legend.text.align = 0)`

Comment: in `stat_summary()` use the same function to dodge as before: `position_dodge2(preserve = "single", width = 0.75)` Otherwise it assumes the default which is `preserve="total"`

Comment: @Mark for next time, I will keep your suggestions in mind. Thank you for your help, it worked.

Comment: @wici thank you, that aligned my means horizontally with the box plots.